# How to retrieve the debug token on exception?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have written my own *ExceptionController* and want to inject the debug token as part of the output.
I had a look on the *WebProfilerToolbarListener*, which is similar to my case but it seems that the exception/error response has another lifecycle.

The *ProfilerCollector* is always called after my listener, which is on the response event.
My Listener needs to be called after the *ProfilerCollector*.

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to use different priorities, but it seems that you need to clear the cache completly. It isn't sufficient to reload the page in development mode.

After changing the priority to **-150** like below it works.

```
profiler_link_listener:
    class:Nerdhive\TheNetwork\TwigBundle\EventListener\ProfilerLinkListener
    priority: -150
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

[image]

You can retrieve the debug token like below:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $token = $response->headers->get('X-Debug-Token');
    // Do here your stuff
}
```

In general **-129** should also work regarding the *WebDebugToolbarListener* or [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-response):

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        KernelEvents::RESPONSE => array('onKernelResponse', -128),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should play with the listener priorities: I guess you are having `RequestDataCollector` listener that have `priority: 0`, you should make it bigger.

Or in other words make the priority of your listener `-1`

[More details about listener priority](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html)